# Spring Data Mongo No accessor to set final property that is initialized

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb, lombok

I have a class that has included a final Set that is already initialized. Mongo converters doesn't see an accessor for the Set field and @Wither doesn't help, because it doesn't generate the method (due to the set being initialized). What can I do?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Wither
@AllArgsConstructor
class A {
  private final Set<String> setOfStrings = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Exception received is

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property final java.util.Set A.setOfStrings
```

I would like to keep the field initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to remove default instantiation and instantiate in the constructor

Comment: For the benefit of others, `@Wither` has been replaced in Lombok by `@With` ;)